# passing argument in high order function javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function doSomething(numbers, doIt){
  numbers.forEach(doIt(number));
}

var result = [];
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
doSomething(arr, function(num){
 result.push(num);
})

console.log(result);
```

Hi,

Why am I getting an error of **"number is not defined"** from above code?
number should be each elements in arr, why is it not defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `doSomething` needs to be like this

```
function doSomething(numbers, doIt) {
    numbers.forEach(doIt); // here you pass the function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function check spelling of number while calling `doIt` the number variable isnt available anywhere so it throws an error.

If you want doIt as callback, you just call it as `numbers.forEach(doIt);`

Answer (score 0):

`doIt(number)` **executes** the function `doIt`, passing the variable `number`. That variable obviously doesn't exist anywhere at the time of calling.

What you actually want is to pass `doIt` as callback to `forEach`, and let `forEach` execute the function, passing it a number. To do that, you just need:

```
function doSomething(numbers, doIt){
  numbers.forEach(doIt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an undefined argument to the `doIt` function.

Change that:

```
numbers.forEach(doIt(number));
```

to this:

```
numbers.forEach(doIt);
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twt6ay1e/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(numbers, doIt){
  numbers.forEach(doIt);
}

var result = [];
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
doSomething(arr, function(num){
 result.push(num);
})

console.log(result);
```

Use this instead, as you are already iterating the numbers array and passing the function as second argument which would carry out `num =>` each item in numbers array.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either pass a closure to forEach to capture the `number` variable to pass to `doIt` or just pass doIt as the forEach callback without calling it.

Capture option:

```
function doSomething(numbers, doIt){ 
  numbers.forEach(function (number) { 
    doIt(number); 
  }); 
} 
var result = []; 
var arr = [1,2,3,4]; 
doSomething(arr, function(num){ 
  result.push(num); 
}); 

console.log(result);
```

Pass as callback option:

```
function doSomething(numbers, doIt){ 
  numbers.forEach(doIt); 
} 
var result = []; 
var arr = [1,2,3,4]; 
doSomething(arr, function(num){ 
  result.push(num); 
}); 

console.log(result);
```